# More than two linearly independent solutions to the (linear second order) radial wave equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, hydrogen

I'm puzzled by the following radial wave equation:

$$ \left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_r}\left(-\frac{d^2}{dr^2} -\frac{2}{r}\frac{d}{dr} + \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\right) + V(r)\right)R_{nl}(r) = ER_{nl}(r)$$

With $V(r) = \frac{-e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}$ and $l = 0$.
This equation comes from the hydrogen atom.

What puzzles me is that there seem to be more than two linear independent solutions. While I thought that it was a standard result that a second order linear ODE has no more than two linear independent solutions.

What am I missing here?

The result about second order ODEs comes from [here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~priyadarshi/MTL101/second_order.pdf)

Comment: How many solutions are there to an infinite well?

Comment: The equation you wrote down has two linearly independent solutions. However, when solving the hydrogen atom, you let $n,l,m$ vary and this gives you many separate equations, all with different values for $n,l,m$, each of which has two linearly independent solutions.

Comment: @JonCuster Is the solution to my puzzle that the result I stated holds only for second order ODEs with Cauchy boundary conditions, and that the infinite square well has Dirichlet boundary conditions?

Comment: @J_P The problem was that the equation I wrote down has more than two linearly independent solutions (I think), that puzzled me. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Do Maxwell’s equations only have two solutions?

Comment: @JonCuster About Maxwell, I presume not, otherwise the people doing Electrical enginering would be bored. Please have a look here: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~priyadarshi/MTL101/second_order.pdf then you see what I mean with the two solutions.

Comment: Maxwell's equations are PDE's, not ODE's. Anyway, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Schr%C3%B6dinger_solution

Comment: Your equation is of the type described in the PDF you link, so it has two linearly independent solutions (note that the coefficients of your ODE have singularities, but I think this particular equation is still regular enough). If you think there are more, what is the third one?

Comment: @J_P From my book, after setting $\rho = \frac{r}{a}$ (where $a$ is some thing related to the Bohr radius). We get solutions $R_{1s} = 2 e^{-\rho}, R_{2s} = (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-\rho/2)2e^{-\rho/2}, R_{3s}=(\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{3}{2}}[1-2(\rho /3) + \frac{2}{3}(\rho/3)^2e^{-\rho/2}$ modulo typos

Comment: Any more solutions? Or just those three?

Comment: The $n$ doesn't appear in the equation, only somehow it is used to parametrize solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94951/discussion-between-j-p-and-jens-wagemaker).

Comment: @J_P I think infinitely many, they come from generalized Laguere polynomials

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, yes, the $n$ isn't a parameter, $l$ is. But also, $E$ is another free parameter - however, when you include the boundary conditions, you get that $E$ can only take on discrete values that you index by $n$.

Comment: So the process is this: you fix $l$ ($0$ in your case) and now you're left with an uncountably infinite number of equations, each for its own $E$. You then solve each of these equations - they all have two linearly independent solutions. Then you find which of those $E$ give you solutions that satisfy the boundary conditions in the first place and only keep those, indexing them as $E_n$. That gives you infinitely many solutions.